# Axios automatically add base url to urls in json responses problem

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I'm using axios server side with Nuxt.js and I `console.log(data)` immediately after `app.$axios.get('...')` and all of the urls in json response are converted to absoulte urls. For example the url in the original json is like `/storage/products/img.jpg` but in the console.log we get `https://example.com/storage/products/img.jpg`

Comment: If there is no http://like path, axios will use current hostname. May be app.$axios is a predefined instance of axios (https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#axioscreateconfig)

Comment: @SergeySuslov No, this convert is happening in json responses not in the request.

Comment: `all of the urls in json response are converted to absoulte urls` - so, in the browser developer tools network tab, you can see just `/storage/products/img.jpg` in the response from the server - but some console.log somewhere in your invisible code shows `https://example.com/storage/products/img.jpg`? perhaps you're console.loging the wrong thing

Comment: @Ali please add a relevant code sample of your Axios call and logging. Without that we can only make very general guesses.

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks but axios run on the server through the Nuxt.js server.

Comment: huh waht? sorry, saw vue.js tag and thought browser was involved